# Prevent developers from unintentionally killing daemon / worker processes on local machine

Tags: node.js, npm, supervisord, forever, node-supervisor

A lot of newbs will kill all their node.js processes on their local machines with

```
pkill -f node
```

Or

```
killall node
```

Etc.

I have a library that uses some daemon processes/workers running on the developer's machine and I will need to restart them if the development "accidentally" kills (all) node.js processes.

The problem is that using NPM libs like `forever`  or `supervisor` will **not** solve this problem because they are node.js processes as well TMK.

Can anyone recommend a daemon watcher / relauncher system that will work on MacOS or *nix?

Perhaps `supervisord` can do what I want to do on both MacOS and *nix? Or perhaps there is another solution to this problem?

Comment: Or perhaps `forever` and `supervisor` can handle the cases where the user issues `pkill -f node` or `killall node`?

Comment: This seems more a question about users permissions on the machine. Also not sure why these _newbs_ would want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote [node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows), [node-mac](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-mac), and [node-linux](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-linux) for this purpose. They are essentially wrappers around node processes, but all three libraries share a common API for managing things like restarts/stop/start/etc.

Comment: Why the downvote? These tools solve this exact problem for thousands of developers.

Comment: I didn't downvote, not sure why someone would do such a thing

Comment: are they wrapped with a node executable or a binary thing? Because if they are wrapped in a node executable, then I assume `pkill -f node` will kill the wrapper process too, which is the problem described in the question.

Comment: The wrapper is not node-based. On windows the parent process is a winsw process, Mac uses a launch daemon, and Linux uses SystemV (SystemD options available too). A `pkill -f node` will still kill the node process, but since node is a child of the wrapper process, the wrapper will restart the node process (if configured to do so).

Comment: ah cool man, now it makes sense, if you  think the original question is a good one, you know what to do, will see if I can make your libs work for me